# How to do a complex where clause involving dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this:

```
Customer     Enrolled
Emp1         01/01/2014
Emp1         02/01/2014
Emp1         03/01/2014
Emp1         04/01/2014
Emp1         05/01/2014
.
.
.
Emp1         12/01/2014
Emp2         12/01/2015
```

I have to identify if an employee was enrolled for an entire year- i.e. has all rows in column 1/1/2014 through 12/01/2014.

I've thought about using a case statement but I'm unsure of what the best approach would be.

This is my current query:

```
select distinct EMPLOYEE from TABLE
WHERE ENROLLED = '2014-01-01' AND ENROLLED = '2014-02-01' AND ENROLLED = '2014-03-01' 
AND ENROLLED = '2014-04-01' AND ENROLLED = '2014-05-01' AND ENROLLED = '2014-06-01' 
AND ENROLLED = '2014-07-01' AND ENROLLED = '2014-08-01' AND ENROLLED = '2014-09-01' 
AND ENROLLED = '2014-10-01' AND ENROLLED = '2014-11-01' AND ENROLLED = '2014-12-01'
```

Maybe I'm just looking at it wrong or over complicating it.

Comment: Your where clause has prevented any rows from ever being returned. A single value can not be all of those dates at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this as a general query that gives you the result for each such customer and each such year:

```
select customer, year(enrolled)
from table
group by customer, year(enrolled)
having count(distinct(enrolled))=12
```

If you are interested only in a particular year or in a particular customer, you can add a `where`-condition like `where year(enrolled)=1024 and customer='emp1'`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for- I hadn't even thought of using the year function

Answer (score 2):

Try this - this will count how many months.

```
select count(Distinct(Enrolled)) from [TABLE] where Enrolled between '1-1-2014' and '12-1-2014' and Customer='Emp1'
```

Comment: Still gets a +1 from me but be careful with those date strings. They will not return the dates you expect depending on the date format. A better format is the ANSI standard YYYYDDMM. That format will work no matter what date format is being used.